# Compute percentage from summed columns?

Tags: sqlite

I'm not sure how to write the SQL query for this.

Here's the table:

```
ZIP;NUMBER
01800;456
02850;445
75001;123
75002;456
75003;789
```

I need to 1. sum the NUMBER column for all rows where ZIP starts with "75", and 2. compute the percentage those rows represent over SUM(NUMBER).

Something like that:

```
select SUM(NUMBER) from MYTABLE WHERE ZIP LIKE "75%" AS 75ZIP;
select (75ZIP/SUM(NUMBER)*100) from MYTABLE;
```

Should I use GROUP BY HAVING, a sub query, or something else entirely?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  100.0 * sum(case when zip like '75%' then number else 0 end) / sum(number)
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, as an alternative, the upcoming 3.30 release supports filtering aggregate functions like can already be done with window functions:

```
SELECT 100.0 * sum(number) FILTER (WHERE zip LIKE '75%') / sum(number)
FROM mytable;
```